# How to get Input stream from URI Content from Drive file

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, drive

While I am selecting **file from Box Drive cloud storage** I am getting URI Like this : content://com.box.android.documents/document/file%2C32851356501
I am not able to get Input stream from its URI. It is Giving FileIOException.

Mean while I am able to get Input stream from URI Content once I get URI like this : file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.box.android/241547485/cache/working/32851356501_e428a6934c285ed493f9c85acf9ab725e6f8f769/backend_1.png

Here is my code for geting Input stream from URI :

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
Uri uri = data.getData();
Log.e(TAG, "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
String mimeType = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().getType(uri);
Log.e(TAG, "File Uri Mime: " + mimeType);

Cursor returnCursor =  getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

try {
    //inputStream = new FileInputStream(uri.getPath());
    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

where data is **Intent data** in my onActivityResult.

Comment: Please read more post in this forum. Not long ago someone had the same problem with box. I think the %2C in `/file%2C32851356501` is the culprit. Try a / instead.

Comment: @greenapps. I replace the character with % to / . Now I am getting exception **requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()**. I have added this code `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />` in manifeast but still no luck.

Comment: Box drive should grand the permissions. Did you meanwhile find that other post? Why do you use  `google-cloud-storage` tag instead of `box-drive` ? Well if it exists. Sorry i have no box drive installed so cannot test it.